# ポップアップテキストの一部がはみ出して表示されてしまう

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

ウォッチ中のタグにカーソルを重ねた際のポップアップ表示で、テキストの一部が枠をはみ出して表示されてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

原文(英語)の「Unwatch Tag」に対して訳文(日本語)が現状「タグのウォッチをやめる」となっており、元の文字数を超えているのが原因です。
表示箇所にもよりますが、翻訳の際はなるべく元の文字数を超えないようするのが望ましいです。本来の意味を損なわない範囲でテキストを省略するのも有効だと思います。

今回の該当箇所は「ウォッチを解除」というテキストで翻訳を新しく[提案](https://ja.traducir.win/string/783)しておきました。

**追記**
変更が反映されていることを確認しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: インポート後に反映されるまで少々お待ちくださいませm_ _m。